# asp.net mvc - nested site deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, iis-7.5

How do I enforce an asp.net mvc application to point to the subfolder instead of root folder.

Lets say I have website called: http://mywebsite

I have got totally different asp.net mvc applications called UserApp and CustomerApp. There is no common thing between them. Now, I want to deploy the application like:

1. http://mywebsite/UserApp/SomeController/SomeAction
2. http://mywebsite/CustomerApp/SomeController/SomeAction

I deployed the application above ways. But, after deployment, only home page works. Any other nested controller/action still points to root path instead of specific path.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set both subfolders as applications in IIS.

Comment: can you please provide link or little more guidance on it?

Comment: http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/12/Creating-IIS7-sites_2C00_-applications_2C00_-and-virtual-directories.aspx

Comment: http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Creating-IIS7-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-using-Internet-Information-Services-Manager.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Slaks is not enough, as default MVC routing is "/controller/action" from the web root.

You could use the IIS routing module to rewrite paths so that http://yourWebSite/UserApp/SomeController/SomeAction is rewrited to http://yourWebSite:8080/SomeController/SomeAction and setup 2 websites on different ports internally.

Or you could modify mvc route mapping. It could work, ... or not. Search for "MapRoute" in MSDN.

Or you could create 2 websites with 2 different hosts.
This is not unusual for 2 unrelated websites :=)